# Maven deploy artifact

Tags: apache2, maven-3

I am using mvn deploy:deploy-file to upload a artifact to the remote repository.
I am having -
Apache2.2 and Maven-3.0.3

Following is the command I am using -

**mvn -X deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://myRepos.com/repo/ -DrepositoryId=repo-mine -Dfile=temp.jar -DgroupId=com.yagnaiq -DartifactId=temp -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=test -DgeneratePom=true -DgeneratePom.description="My POM" -DrepositoryLayout=default -DuniqueVersion=false**

My settings.xml contains an entry for repositoryId as-

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>repo-mine</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </server>  </servers>
```

I am getting following error -

**Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://myRepos.com/repo/com/yagnaiq/temp/1.0/temp-1.0-test.jar. Return code is: 500**

Need help on this!

THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 means something went wrong on the remote server. You should check the logs on the myrepos.com server. (Maybe it's out of disk space or something).

Comment: I am getting following error in the error.log


A lock database was not specified with the DAVLockDB directive. One must be specified to use the locking functionality.  [500, #401]

Comment: Sounds like your repository is misconfigured somehow. Can you upload any artefacts at all? Could you update the question with details of your repository setup?

Comment: Hey I have resolved the issue. Above error was there as i enabled the DAV module provided by apache server to allow http put. The error was there as the dir at which I had specified the DAVLockDB was not present.
To specify this we have to include a line in httpd.conf as 

DavLockDB "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/var/DavLock"

The dir var was not present hence i got the internal server error, and after creating that dir the error got resolved.